# Three.JS loader examples not working on Firefox, Kubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla, recently upgraded

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 20.10

Try this example in Firefox:  https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_stl

Try more of the other examples too!  The model doesn't seem to show up in Firefox.

Works okay in Chrome, but Firefox appears to be default Kubuntu browser, so...

Wondering if 3D Web Canvas doesn't work too well in Firefox.  I will try a few more tests.

Comment: I have confirmed that Three.JS, X_ITE and X3DOM do not work in Firefox Kubuntu 20.10 (upgraded)

Comment: I just upgraded again.  No fix apparent.

Comment: fixed now!  I upgraded grub